# Function for ids based on sowing date-harvest date duration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I want to keep only the rows from  column for the period between the <sowing_date> and <harvest_date> based on ID because every id has different sowing date and harvest date

ID    time        NDVI      sowing_date harvesting_date
106   2020-03-01  0.307967  2020-04-21  2020-11-01
106   2020-03-02  0.299089  2020-04-21  2020-11-01
106   2020-03-03  0.290211  2020-04-21  2020-11-01

I tried through groupby but it doesn't work properly and I think only through a function or a for loop this can work. Please any thoughts?

The expected outcome should be like below

ID    time        NDVI      sowing_date harvesting_date
106   2020-04-21  0.307967  2020-04-21  2020-11-01
106   2020-04-22  0.299089  2020-04-21  2020-11-01
...
106   2020-11-01  0.290211  2020-04-21  2020-11-01

Comment: You want only rows where column "time" is >= sowing_date and <= harvesting_date?

Comment: That's correct @VincentRupp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically just a filter then. One common way of filtering a dataframe is to create a list of True/False for each line and then filter on that. This looks something like:

```
filter = [(df.time <= df.harvesting_date) & (df.time >= df.sowing_date)]
filtered_df = df[filter]
```

You could also do that in one line, but this makes it easier to see what "filter" is doing, if you are interested.

A word of caution though! Be sure those dates are datetime objects; dates often show as as strings, so you'd need to use something like `strptime()` to change them.

Hope this helps!